# Not being able to disable windows 11 auto login

Tags: windows, passwords, windows-11, login, auto-login

So, my windows 11 keeps auto signing in the last used account despite trying every possible solution to disable i was able to find. I have 2 admin accounts, one for work that is password protected, and one for personal used that has no password. The netplwiz checkbox to enforce password access is already checked, registry AutoAdminLogon is set to 0, fast boot is off and some other registry tweaks i tried that failed to work.

The weirdest thing is that if i last logged in with the password protected account, the next time i boot up the computer, even though it shows me the login screen i can already hear Microsoft Teams notifications, and after login in i can see that all the applications are already running, even before i entered the account. If instead i login on the personal account, when i try to shut down it says another user is logged in, even though i have not logged in with the other user for the session.

If i last used the personal account, it just automatically logs in to this account without prompting me the login screen.

I cannot stress how much it is pissing me off that i am not being able to change this behavior in a simple manner. I just want it to show me the login screen every time i boot up, so that i can choose which user to login to.

Comment: Turn OFF windows 11 auto login.   https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery/windows-11-auto-login.html    ... I don't use auto login and no difficulty iusing whatever account I want.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: @John As i have written in the question, all of these solutions have been done and still having the issue.

Comment: There is something wrong with the OS.  It also appears to be Windows User Profile damage. The most straightforward way to fix this is to back up and reinstall Windows 11.